# Asp.Net5 EnableCors not working

Tags: asp.net, cors, asp.net-core-mvc

My Asp.Net5 Web Api is not working on Chrome, this is due to a CORS issue and seems that my CORS configuration is conflicting with my OAuthBearerAuthentication.
In my Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddCors();
    services.ConfigureCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()));
```

My controller looks like:

```
    [Authorize(OAuthBearerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    public class MyController
```

Then I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

However, if I remove the authorize attribute:

```
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    public class MyController
```

Then I am allowed... What is going on?

Comment: How did you solved this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the following into the `system.webServer` section of the web.config file:

```
 <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-length, content-type" />
   </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

Modify the methods and headers as necessary. You cannot use * in those headers. It will also allow you to request content like images and HTML with AJAX, not just controller action served resources.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, clear cache on chrome, and try in edge. Chrome is eating your errors.

See the request, you should have 2.
PREFLIGHT and the request itself.

If preflight (OPTIONS) fails, the request is not even made.

Normally preflights fail because Server error 500. Exceptions does not include cors headers so this may be your issue here.

Ok, now, the problem is chrome won't show the error ANYWHERE.
So, you can inspect the request on EDGE, which will give you an actual error (you must use developer console, the error won't show on the browser) or use fiddler.

Now that you can see your error, you may probably know how to continue, but to add a little bit of what I faced myself:

1. If you have `services.AddMvc()`, this already adds cors to the pipeline, so adding it using `services.AddCors()` again throws a key already found exception. (I think it's a bug, may file an issue on github).
2. to configure cors when AddMvc is used you do like this:

   ```
   services.ConfigureCors(options =>
                       options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                           .AllowCredentials()
                                                           .AllowAnyHeader()));
   ```
3. to actually add cors to the pipeline, you need to do         `app.UseCors("AllowAll");` on Configure method.
4. if you are using `app.MapWhen` take care that MapWhen forks, so you may need to specify UseCors for all the branches you are using with MapWhen that need cors, like your api endpoints. (If you have no idea of what I'm talking about here, just ignore it.)